# API Automation - Is it possible to get response of the post call

Tags: api, automation, gmail-api, frisby.js

I'm learning how to automate API with frisby.js on gmail.api.
I want to create a test where I create and delete(or send) a Draft message.

So I wrote a test which creates a Draft and my question is - can I write a code that gets at least ID of generated response from my Post call?

```
    var frisby = require('frisby');
frisby.create('Create Draft Google')
    .post('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?access_token=*my-token-here*', {
        message: {
            raw: "RGFuJ3MgVG9vbHMgYXJlIGNvb2wh",
            id: "1547265285486966899"
        }
        }, { json: true })
        .inspectJSON()
        .inspectBody()
    .expectStatus(200)
.toss();
```

So, to clarify, I want to write another part of THIS^ test with

```
.after(function(err, res, body){}
```

Steps:

1. I create a Draft message
2. I want my test to automatically get ID of just created Draft
3. So I could Delete it\Send it

Thanks!

Comment: Here, I found some possibile solution. I just don't know how does it work :( Help me, please

Comment: `var frisby = require('frisby');
frisby.create('Create Draft Google')
 .post('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?access_token=[]', {
 message: {
   raw: "RGFu...",
  }
  }, { json: true })
  .inspectJSON()
  .inspectBody()
 .expectStatus(200)
 .afterJSON(function (err, res, body) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(body);
  var Id = obj.headers[constants.ID_HEADER_KEY]; 
  frisby.create('Delete Google Draft Test')
   .delete('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/' +Id.ID_HEADER_KEY +'?access_token=[]', {})
   .expectStatus(204) 
  .toss();
  })
.toss();`

Comment: Sorry that formatting is lost. I just think that I use variable wrongly. The problem is there's no proper documentation

Comment: I'm getting "[SyntaxError: Unexpected Token u]" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.afterJSON(function(json){
    callback(json.id);
})
```

I used this function and it worked. Thanks to my friend for help :D

Here're full tests if someone needs it:
This is how I get an ID of created Draft

```
var frisby = require('frisby');
var new_id = function(frisby, callback)
{
frisby.create('Create Draft Google')
    .post('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?access_token=[my_token]', {
        message: {
            raw: "RGFu...",
        }
        }, { json: true })
        .inspectJSON()
        .inspectBody()
    .expectStatus(200)
    .afterJSON(function(json){
        callback(json.id);
    })
    .toss();
};
module.exports = new_id;
```

This is how I used it to delete this Draft

```
var frisby = require('frisby');
var getid_spec = require("./getid_spec.js");
getid_spec(frisby,function(id){
frisby.create('Delete Google Draft Test')
        .delete("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/" +id +"?access_token=[my_token]", {})
        .expectStatus(204)  
    .toss();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a draft, you will get the id of the newly created draft in the response:

**Request**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?access_token={access_token}

{
 "message": {
  "raw": "RnJ..."
 }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "id": "r5019331921817638435",
 "message": {
  "id": "157948187e41b5bb",
  "threadId": "157948187e41b5bb",
  "labelIds": [
   "DRAFT"
  ]
 }
}
```

Then you can use this id to either [**send**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/send) or [**delete**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/delete) the message.

Comment: Thank you! But I know that :) Is there a possibility that frisby.js will get that information on it's own? Right when it get Response can it automatically get ID, for example?  Or it is possible only manually?